# PhantomJS Using the webserver module

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to scrape a webpage. I am successful in scraping it on command prompt. But I am unable to use the web server module at all.

[I am using this link as reference](http://benjaminbenben.com/2013/07/28/phantomjs-webserver/)

**Using the webserver module, is not working for me**

I get this page after following the instrction in the above link. I think I am missing linking to web server

[image]

Comment: Please describe what the problem is, because *"I am unable to use the web server module at all"* is not an accurate description of the problem. Show your code and describe how it behaves.

Comment: @ArtjomB., thanks for your comments, Follwing the instruction on web page  I get this                                                                              https://z-1-scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/11892182_10207482676013408_1156186947729031170_n.jpg?oh=35ceaf0beca08eb103931ce48fc5596a&oe=56778E45

Comment: Okay, will do from next time, thanks

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the tutorial that fiddler is used. What did you expect to happen? You haven't said what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know why it is showing fiddler, I don't need it. I want to see localhost:8080 as stated in tutorial, with parsed data.